# NUMA memory allocation with hwloc

Tags: c++, memory, valgrind, allocation, numa

I'm trying to do NUMA aware memory allocation with hwloc and get somewhat strange behavior.

My goal is to allocate blocks of memory on different NUMA nodes as i need this for a project. To verify that the correct amount of memory is allocated i have been using valgrind's memcheck tool. The tool reports always the same amount of bytes allocated no matter how many elements i want to allocate, which doesn't make sense to me. And overall the  number of allocations seems to high. I do understand that hwloc needs to allocate some stuff internally to work properly but still this doesn't make sense to me.

Even if i try to allocate a bigger chunk of memory the allocated bytes reported by valgrind remain the same.

Here is the code i have been using to allocate memory on NUMA node 0.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <hwloc.h>

int main() {
    hwloc_topology_t topo;
    hwloc_topology_init(&topo);
    hwloc_topology_load(topo);

    auto node = hwloc_get_obj_by_type(topo, HWLOC_OBJ_NUMANODE, 0);

    auto mem = hwloc_alloc_membind(topo, SIZE * sizeof(float), node->nodeset,
                    HWLOC_MEMBIND_BIND, HWLOC_MEMBIND_STRICT | HWLOC_MEMBIND_BYNODESET);

    if (mem == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Allocation failed" << std::endl;
    }   

    hwloc_free(topo, mem, SIZE);
    hwloc_topology_destroy(topo);
}
```

and this is the relevant part of the valgrind memcheck report:
[valgrind report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvyKw.png)

Really hope some can explain what is going on here.

I'm using hwloc 2.7.1 and valgrind 3.15.0

Comment: What is SIZE? You code won't compile without it.

Comment: Literally doesn't matter for the output i'm getting, Thats why i did not include it.

Comment: OK, but in that case you should say so in your question to help people trying to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Valgrind 3.15 is quite old - can you try something more recent?

To see everything you need to use

`valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes --default-suppressions=no`

With that I get (using a SIZE of 1024)

```
==1709== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1709==     in use at exit: 2,777 bytes in 4 blocks
==1709==   total heap usage: 224 allocs, 220 frees, 31,139 bytes allocated
==1709== 
==1709== 9 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 4
==1709==    at 0x484CBC4: malloc (in /usr/local/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-freebsd.so)
==1709==    by 0x48A060D: ??? (in /usr/local/lib/libhwloc.so.15.6.0)
==1709==    by 0x48751E5: hwloc_topology_load (in /usr/local/lib/libhwloc.so.15.6.0)
==1709==    by 0x202980: main (hwloc.cpp:7)
==1709== 
==1709== 64 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 4
==1709==    at 0x48500D5: calloc (in /usr/local/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-freebsd.so)
==1709==    by 0x4FFD7B2: ??? (in /lib/libthr.so.3)
==1709==    by 0x4FF5FC9: ??? (in /lib/libthr.so.3)
==1709==    by 0x4FF5139: ??? (in /lib/libthr.so.3)
==1709==    by 0x400B0FC: ??? (in /libexec/ld-elf.so.1)
==1709==    by 0x400938A: ??? (in /libexec/ld-elf.so.1)
==1709==    by 0x4006F88: ??? (in /libexec/ld-elf.so.1)
==1709== 
==1709== 1,040 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 3 of 4
==1709==    at 0x484CBC4: malloc (in /usr/local/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-freebsd.so)
==1709==    by 0x4B57254: ??? (in /lib/libc.so.7)
==1709==    by 0x4B573D2: __cxa_atexit (in /lib/libc.so.7)
==1709==    by 0x4E53A68: ??? (in /usr/local/lib/libze_loader.so.1.8.12)
==1709==    by 0x400B0FC: ??? (in /libexec/ld-elf.so.1)
==1709==    by 0x400938A: ??? (in /libexec/ld-elf.so.1)
==1709==    by 0x4006F88: ??? (in /libexec/ld-elf.so.1)
==1709== 
==1709== 1,664 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 4 of 4
==1709==    at 0x48500D5: calloc (in /usr/local/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-freebsd.so)
==1709==    by 0x4FF5FB8: ??? (in /lib/libthr.so.3)
==1709==    by 0x4FF5139: ??? (in /lib/libthr.so.3)
==1709==    by 0x400B0FC: ??? (in /libexec/ld-elf.so.1)
==1709==    by 0x400938A: ??? (in /libexec/ld-elf.so.1)
==1709==    by 0x4006F88: ??? (in /libexec/ld-elf.so.1)
==1709== 
==1709== LEAK SUMMARY:
==1709==    definitely lost: 9 bytes in 1 blocks
==1709==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1709==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1709==    still reachable: 2,768 bytes in 3 blocks
==1709==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Also try using `--trace-malloc=yes` to see all of the allocation and deallocation calls.

Comment: Sadly i can't upgrade valgrind on the system i'm working on. Thanks for the hint on using the parameters. Your results seem a lot more reasonable than mine so maybe it's just a problem with my valgrind version.

Comment: No it will be the OS and library versions that matter.